# How to delete objects in Realm?

Tags: ios, realm

Deletion in Realm seems to be incredibly underdocumented ... or am I missing something?  How do you delete objects from Lists?  Where are the examples?

I have object A with a List.
I have another object B also with a List
C has a reference back up to its parent A

I want to delete a B and all its sub-objects C.  If I delete a C I want to remove it from its parent collection A as well.

I am stumped ... and find it unbelievable that Realm docs provide only two examples:

```
try! realm.write {
  realm.delete(cheeseBook)
}
try! realm.write {
  realm.deleteAll()
}
```

Answer (score 15):

First off the bat, you shouldn't ever need to manually implement a reference from a child back up to its parent. Realm implements [an inverse relationship](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) feature that lets children objects automatically look up which objects they belong to.

```
class C: Object {
    let parent = LinkingObjects(fromType: A.self, property: "c")
}
```

Realm does not support cascading deletes yet (There's [an issue for it here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1186) ) so it's not enough to simply delete a top level object and expect any objects in `List` properties of that object to also get deleted. It's necessary to capture those objects directly, and manually delete them before you then delete its parent.

```
let childObjects = b.subObjects
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(childObjects)
    realm.delete(b)
}
```

(That SHOULD work, but if it doesn't, copy all of the sub-objects to a normal Swift array instead and do it from there)

If you delete an `Object` outright, it will also be removed from any `List` instances, so deleting C should remove its reference in A automatically.

Sorry you're having trouble! I've logged an issue suggesting that the documentation on deleting objects from Realm is reviewed and improved. :)

Comment: Wow seven months later and still no improvement :(

Comment: It's not a high priority feature for us at the moment. But do feel free to chime in on the GitHub issue tracking this feature to add your support. :) https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1186

Answer (score 4):

There is an implementation of a Realm extension for cascading Deletion in Swift 4. You can find it in GitHub Link ->(https://gist.github.com/verebes1/02950e46fff91456f2ad359b3f3ec3d9). After adding this extension in your code using it will be as simple as placing a flag on the delete method.

```
realm.delete(object, cascading: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Genius!